# Ajax not post base64 data of large image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, base64

I am passing Image base64 data through ajax to my php function, but for large size image Ajax does not post the data. But the same code works perfectly for small images.

```
srcdata=data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4SxvRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAANAAABBAABAAAAwAwAAAEBBAABAAAALAcAAA8BAgAIAAAAqgAAABABAgARAAAAsgAAABIBAwABAAAABgAAABoBBQABAAAAxAAAABsBBQABAAAAzAAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAMAAAA1AAAADIBAgAUAAAA4AAAABMCAwABAAAAAQAAAGmHBAABAAAA9AAAACWIBAABAAAA3gkAAPAJAABTQU1TVU5HAFNBTVNVTkctU0dILUk1MzcAAEgAAAABAAAASAAAAAEAAABJNTM3VUNVQ05DOQAyMDE0OjA2OjIyIDEwOjE3OjEwACEAmoIFAAEAAACGAgAAnYIFAAEAAACOAgAAIogDAAEAAAADAAAAJ4gDAAEAAAB9AAAAAJAHAAQAAAAwMjIwA5ACABQAAACWAgAABJACABQAAACqAgAAAZEHAAQAAAABAgMAAZIKAAEAAAC 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 giAABS0pLSmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFmWAACWZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABZlwAAlmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAWZcAAJZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABlVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFmXAACWZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABplwAAlVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABZlwAAlmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAaZcAAJVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAWZcAAJZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGmXAACVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFmXAACWZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABplwAAlVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABZlwAAlmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAaZcAAJVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAWZcAAJmXAACWZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGmXAACVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFmWAACZlwAAlmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABZlgAAmZcAAJZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAYRUAABmXAACWZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZLSktKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASLAAAf/8AACRQAABVo8AAf/3AAB25wABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATv8AAf/2AACFNwABTv8AAf/2AACFNwABT5QAAf/2AACFXgABT5QAAf/2AACFXgABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEtKABYAAEZBRkEAHIjEAAEAHOcsAAEAMRzRAAIARn5sAAIAWwYuAAMAcAgFAAMAmtFlAAEAmnjxAAEAmpN5AAEAjPohAAEAfnrCAAIAcNwgAAIAYjlTAAMAVDJzAAMARuH8AAIAVOH8AAIBgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAAAAAAARkFGQQADAD8AAwArAABGQUZBABg8AAAAPAAAAFMwOFFFTENHQzAxAAcAAQAHAAQAAAAwMTAwAgAEAAEAAAAAIAEADAAEAAEAAAAAAAAAEAAFAAEAAABaAAAAQAAEAAEAAAAAAAAAUAAEAAEAAAABAAAAAAEDAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgABAAIABAAAAFI5OAACAAcABAAAADAxMDAAAAAAAQAAAAEABAAAAAICAAAAAAAACQAAAQQAAQAAAAABAAABAQQAAQAAAJAAAAADAQMAAQAAAAYAAAASAQMAAQAAAAYAAAAaAQUAAQA `
```

data is too large so partially posted ,

**ajax**

```
count = 1;
name='test'
jQuery.ajax({
    url:"/createImage.php",
    data:{img_data:srcdata,img_id:count,name:name},
    type:"POST",
    contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    success:function(result)
    {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
print_r($_POST); // is empty when logging..
```

When I'm trying to get the post data in php I am getting empty .
What could be the reason for ajax not sending the data when base64 is used.

Comment: Sounds line a server size setting, not a sender problem. What are the sizes that fail vs works?

Comment: failed when trying 2MB images.

Comment: Sounds like a default sever setting. PHP is not my bag, but Googling the server issue should give loads of results.

Comment: I will check and comback here.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie But I am sending as a variable, how to set maximum value for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with [TrueBlueAussie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201078/trueblueaussie). This looks like a server side setting in PHP.

Open you `php.ini` file and find the line stating `upload_max_filesize`. The default it set to 2M, which is 2MB. Try increasing it to 3MB and see if you are still receiving the error.

Note: You'll need to restart Apache/Nginx/webserver for this to take affect from the `php.ini` file.

Even though you are sending the file as a variable, the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` might be interpreted in PHP as being an actual file upload. The other `php.ini` setting you can take a look at will be `post_max_size` which has a default of 8M, which is the maximum that you can POST to your PHP script.

Comment: yes i solved .problem is post_max_size param.. when i am getting 2M size image to base64 data it will become 4 time greater than original size , so 8M is reached..I changed this 8M based on my Requirement.

Comment: yes I solved. values were upload_max_filesize=2M & post_max_size =8M as default. And my AJAX request size was (image 1) 81.89kB & Image 2 108.48kB as in network inspector. First image was gone thorugh but second was failed. But after I changed the values to upload_max_filesize=20M & post_max_size =80M, it's sucess for both.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: the code that you indicate in base64 returns a corrupted image;
when you send the code in base64, uses the function encodeURIComponent to avoid errors when sending.

Try this code:

```js
 var srcdata = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4SxvRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAANAAABBAABAAAAwAwAAAEBBAABAAAALAcAAA8BAgAIAAAAqgAAABABAgARAAAAsgAAABIBAwABAAAABgAAABoBBQABAAAAxAAAABsBBQABAAAAzAAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAMAAAA1AAAADIBAgAUAAAA4AAAABMCAwABAAAAAQAAAGmHBAABAAAA9AAAACWIBAABAAAA3gkAAPAJAABTQU1TVU5HAFNBTVNVTkctU0dILUk1MzcAAEgAAAABAAAASAAAAAEAAABJNTM3VUNVQ05DOQAyMDE0OjA2OjIyIDEwOjE3OjEwACEAmoIFAAEAAACGAgAAnYIFAAEAAACOAgAAIogDAAEAAAADAAAAJ4gDAAEAAAB9AAAAAJAHAAQAAAAwMjIwA5ACABQAAACWAgAABJACABQAAACqAgAAAZEHAAQAAAABAgMAAZIKAAEAAAC 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 giAABS0pLSmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFmWAACWZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABZlwAAlmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAWZcAAJZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABlVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFmXAACWZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABplwAAlVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABZlwAAlmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAaZcAAJVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAWZcAAJZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGmXAACVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFmXAACWZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABplwAAlVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABZlwAAlmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAaZcAAJVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAWZcAAJmXAACWZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGmXAACVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFmWAACZlwAAlmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABVVxAAVVcQAFVXEABZlgAAmZcAAJZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAYRUAABmXAACWZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZmcQAGZnEABmZxAAZLSktKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASLAAAf/8AACRQAABVo8AAf/3AAB25wABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATv8AAf/2AACFNwABTv8AAf/2AACFNwABT5QAAf/2AACFXgABT5QAAf/2AACFXgABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEtKABYAAEZBRkEAHIjEAAEAHOcsAAEAMRzRAAIARn5sAAIAWwYuAAMAcAgFAAMAmtFlAAEAmnjxAAEAmpN5AAEAjPohAAEAfnrCAAIAcNwgAAIAYjlTAAMAVDJzAAMARuH8AAIAVOH8AAIBgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAABgQAAAAAAAAAARkFGQQADAD8AAwArAABGQUZBABg8AAAAPAAAAFMwOFFFTENHQzAxAAcAAQAHAAQAAAAwMTAwAgAEAAEAAAAAIAEADAAEAAEAAAAAAAAAEAAFAAEAAABaAAAAQAAEAAEAAAAAAAAAUAAEAAEAAAABAAAAAAEDAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgABAAIABAAAAFI5OAACAAcABAAAADAxMDAAAAAAAQAAAAEABAAAAAICAAAAAAAACQAAAQQAAQAAAAABAAABAQQAAQAAAJAAAAADAQMAAQAAAAYAAAASAQMAAQAAAAYAAAAaAQUAAQA `";

 var count = 1;
 var name = 'test';

 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./createImage.php",
  data: { img_data:srcdata, img_id:count, name:name },
  cache: false,
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  success: function (result) {
   alert(result);
  }

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've already stated that i have not posted whole data,because it is too large.

Comment: Doesnt work, sorry ... like @ManikandanArunachalam said, it is a size problem