# Trying to Post data to my Rest API

Tags: javascript, rest

I have a REST API and I need to poost base 64 data to it from my Javascript.

This is my code-behind:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Services/Image/Upload")]
public void Upload(string imageData)
{
    does stuff
}

 var url = "http://informedworker.co.uk/api/Services/Image/Upload?" +"imageData=" +  base64;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post(url)
        .done(function (url) {
            // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
            $("#error").html("Done");
        })
     .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
         $('#error').html('Error: ' + err);
     });
});
```

but I get an error 'not found'.

Is it the way I am passing my parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296252/ajax-not-post-base64-data-of-large-image

Comment: @AhmedKhan thanks but the fix is in Php and I am using MVC/ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

You're POST excpects a link like "Services/Image/Upload?imageData=",
but you're link looks like "Services/Image/Upload?base64=imageData="

You need to pass the base64 value into an object called imageData

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var imageData = base64;
$.post(url, imageData)
    .done(function (url) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $("#error").html("Done");
    })
 .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
     $('#error').html('Error: ' + err);
 });
});
```

or write the the called url like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.post(url + "?imageData=" + base64)
    .done(function (url) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $("#error").html("Done");
    })
 .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
     $('#error').html('Error: ' + err);
 });
});
```

Comment: The other solution might be to convert the image to Base64 in backend as well.

Comment: thanks that was stupid tempo. I have amedned the question but it astill does not work

Comment: Do you still have the same error or something diffrent?